# C execvp /bin/sh - interact programatically (dup2 stdin/stdout, etc)

Tags: c

I'm using the following code to create a child process. The idea is to filter (more generally speaking execute an arbitrary function on) stdin and stdout of the child.
For one shots this example should work, but for an interactive shell there are things missing to work. The question is basically: Is this the right way to achieve what I want? What am I missing? (e.g. I tried to catch all signals (execept STOP and KILL) and relay them to the child, but it didnt really help much)

I'm eager to understand the issue so I'd be glad for any help and insight on that matter

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
/* since pipes are unidirectional, we need two pipes.
   one for data to flow from parent's stdout to child's
   stdin and the other for child's stdout to flow to
   parent's stdin */
 
#define NUM_PIPES          2

#define PARENT_WRITE_PIPE  0
#define PARENT_READ_PIPE   1
 
int pipes[NUM_PIPES][2];
 
/* always in a pipe[], pipe[0] is for read and 
   pipe[1] is for write */
#define READ_FD  0
#define WRITE_FD 1
 
#define PARENT_FROM_CHILD_FD  ( pipes[PARENT_READ_PIPE][READ_FD]   )
#define PARENT_TO_CHILD_FD ( pipes[PARENT_WRITE_PIPE][WRITE_FD] )
 
#define CHILD_FROM_PARENT_FD   ( pipes[PARENT_WRITE_PIPE][READ_FD]  )
#define CHILD_TO_PARENT_FD  ( pipes[PARENT_READ_PIPE][WRITE_FD]  )


pid_t pid;

void filterStream( char* buffer, int count){
    printf("filter\n");
}

int main () {
    // pipes for parent to write and read
    pipe(pipes[PARENT_READ_PIPE]);
    pipe(pipes[PARENT_WRITE_PIPE]);

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid==0){
        /*child*/
        char *argv[]={ "sh","-i",0};
         
        dup2(CHILD_FROM_PARENT_FD, STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(CHILD_TO_PARENT_FD, STDOUT_FILENO);

        //edit
        close(CHILD_FROM_PARENT_FD);
        close(CHILD_TO_PARENT_FD);
        close(PARENT_FROM_CHILD_FD);
        close(PARENT_TO_CHILD_FD);

        execvp(argv[0], argv);
    } else {
        /*parent*/
        char buffer[8192];
        int count;
        int buflen=sizeof(buffer)-1;
        /* close fds not required by parent */       
        close(CHILD_FROM_PARENT_FD);
        close(CHILD_TO_PARENT_FD);
        while(1){
            // read stdin
            while((count = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, buflen))>0){
                filterStream(buffer,count);
                buffer[count] = 0;
                write(PARENT_TO_CHILD_FD,buffer,count);
                if (count<buflen){
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (count<0){
                printf("IOERR: %d\n",errno);
            }
            
            // Read from child’s stdout
            while((count = read(PARENT_FROM_CHILD_FD, buffer, buflen))>0){
                filterStream(buffer,count);
                buffer[count] = 0;
                write(STDOUT_FILENO,buffer,count);
                if (count<buflen){
                    break;
                }
            } 
            if (count<0){
                printf("IOERR2: %d\n",errno);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem 1:
After the first command no further commands are executed: Is this just a redirection problem from parent to child or is it deeper?

```sh
./a.out
sh-5.1$ touch test
filter
touch test
sh-5.1$ exit

# hangs
^C
sh-5.1$ exit

# hangs...
```

Problem 2: on some commands the shell just backgrounds: Who backgrounds it exactly?

```sh
./a.out
sh-5.1$ whoami
filter
whoami
filter
currentuser
[1]  + 238242 suspended (tty input)  ./a.out
```

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child process (or the parent).
**Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible. In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited the source code (see //edit) but it does not affect to program.

Comment: In the parent code, you have: `while((count = read(PARENT_FROM_CHILD_FD, buffer, buflen))>0){` — this loop won't terminate until the child process terminates, so you never get a chance to enter a new command.  You're going to have to do some rethinking.  Maybe you close the write pipe from parent to child after writing the command (so the shell exits after executing a single line of commands).  Maybe you devise some other method.  Remember, some commands produce no output at all.\